# Decision trees (деревья решений) в OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

У меня есть таблица с данными о погоде и количестве лесных пожаров в некоторые дни в некотором регионе:

```
Температура | Влажность | Скорость ветра | ... | Количество лесных пожаров
```

Все данные представлены в виде чисел.

Требуется по этим данным построить дерево решений, и, с помощью него и входных параметров (температура, влажность, скорость ветра, и т.д.) спрогнозировать количество лесных пожаров.

Для работы с деревьями решений в *OpenCV* есть класс `CvDTree`. Для построения дерева решений в данном классе есть метод `train`:

```
boolean train(Mat trainData, int tflag, Mat responses)
```

Как (каким образом и в каком порядке) преобразовать мои входные данные в `Mat trainData`?

Возможно, отвечающему поможет обсуждение [по этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948837/decision-trees-in-opencv)

Comment: @LEQADA, было бы лучше если бы Вы выбрали вопрос, к которому есть общедоступный набор данных

Comment: @Oceinic, зачем вам набор? Здесь нужно привести пример, рассказать о том, как нужно делать и почему, дать ссылки. Не нужно решать задачу за ТС.

Comment: _"подробно распишет"_ -- подробно в книге "OpenCV 3.0 Computer Vision with Java". пример на java - [тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LFtICgAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&dq=opencv+decision+tree+data&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0x8Ozz_DJAhUiinIKHV3lC0cQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=opencv%20decision%20tree%20data&f=false). написать это как ответ не могу, т.к. ответы-ссылки не приветствуются. и публиковать в ответе скриншоты листингов из книги не могу, т.к. возможно нарушение копирайта.

Comment: @Stack, таким макаром можно отвечать на 99% процентов вопросов всего SO. Вы читали это: [Как написать хороший ответ?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @LEQADA _"таким макаром можно отвечать на 99% процентов вопросов всего SO"_ -- поверю на слово. но у любого правила бывают исключения. обычно я пишу код, который решает задачу. но opencv и java я не знаю. а так-как на вопрос  нет ни одного ответа, то поэтому лучше дать ссылку, чем ничего. но вы можете, если хотите скопировать сами листинг из книги. а я не буду, уже объяснял причину.

Comment: @LEQADA _"Вы читали это"_ -- читал. а вы почитайте [это](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8?cb=1) -- как видите мой ответ не самый плохой)

Answer (score 2):

Сделал небольшой пример (можно посмотреть тут https://github.com/NorsaG/OpenCVExample)

Некоторые мысли по задаче:

- выбор инструмента (лично мое мнение - есть более удачные решения, тот
  же xgboost или  spark mllib)
- выбор критерия (определять число -
  задача сложная, а вот факт преодоления определённой границы нет)
- Тестовые данные из головы, поэтому не сильно видны какие либо зависимости (даже очевидные для нас).
- ненавижу нативные инструменты для java :) Кроме того, похожий код (с
  минимальными исправлениями в виде имен классов) полностью отказался
  работать на последней версии либы.

package org.firerate;

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.ml.CvRTParams;
import org.opencv.ml.CvRTrees;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;


public class FireRateExample {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
private static final int[] OFFSETS = {0, 5, 9}; // границы чисел. будем проверять и прогнозировать эти ситуации

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// загружаем данные
    List<String> csv = loadFile("fire_test.txt");
    CvRTrees tree;
    // настройка параметров. с этим можно долго и упорно играться, подгоняя так или иначе под модель
    CvRTParams params = new CvRTParams();
    params.set_max_depth(2);

    Mat trainData;
    Mat labels;
    // строим модель для ситуаций: кол-во пожаров > 0, > 5 и > 9
    for (int offset : OFFSETS) {
        tree = new CvRTrees();
        // создаем матрицу тренировочных данных размерности: х-1 чтобы отбросить названия колонок, 3 - количество критериев (CvType.CV_32F - тип данных)
        trainData = new Mat(csv.size() - 1, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
        // классификатор -> 0 или 1 (в нашем случае - количество пожаров больше определенного значения? проставляться будет позднее)
        labels = new Mat(csv.size() - 1, 1, CvType.CV_32S);
        // загружаем построчно данные и проставляем их в матрицы
        for (int i = 1; i < csv.size(); i++) {
            String line = csv.get(i);
            String[] str = line.split(",");
            trainData.put(i - 1, 0, new float[]{Float.valueOf(str[0]), Float.valueOf(str[1]), Float.valueOf(str[2])});
            labels.put(i - 1, 0, new int[]{Integer.valueOf(str[3]) > offset ? 1 : 0});
        }
        // тренируем и тестируем модель
        // 1-й параметр: входная модель без класса
        // 2-й параметр: тип входных данных (колонки(0) или строки(1))
        // 3-й параметр: значения для входных данных
        // tree.train(trainData, 1, labels);
        // 8-й параметр: параметры дерева
        tree.train(trainData, 1, labels, new Mat(), new Mat(), new Mat(), new Mat(), params);
        testModel(tree, offset);
    }
}


private static List<String> loadFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
}

private static void testModel(CvRTrees tree, int offset) {
    System.out.println("!!!!! Test model with count of fires more than " + offset + "!!!!!");
    //пример. номер примера, температура, влажность, сила ветра
    testExample(tree, offset, 1, 28, 0.20f, 3);
    testExample(tree, offset, 2, 28, 0.90f, 3);

    testExample(tree, offset, 3, 35, 0.80f, 3);
    testExample(tree, offset, 4, 20, 0.80f, 3);

    testExample(tree, offset, 5, 25, 0.70f, 1);
    testExample(tree, offset, 6, 25, 0.70f, 6);
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}


private static void testExample(CvRTrees tree, int offset, int number, float temp, float humidity, float wind) {
    Mat ex = new Mat(1, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
    ex.put(0, 0, new float[]{temp, humidity, wind});

    System.out.println("Example " + number + "(count of fires -> " + offset + "): " + ex.dump());
    // предсказываем событие. 1 - событие произойдет
    // в нашем случае означает, что произойдет <offset> число пожаров
    System.out.println(tree.predict(ex));
    // вероятность события (появления 1)
    System.out.println(tree.predict_prob(ex));
}
```

}